# AWS Neptune workbench visualisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, vis.js, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I am using Jupter notebook on AWS Neptune to query data from the graph. Is it possible to set the colour of nodes with specific label to different colour?

For eg, can I set the node colour to `red` if the node label is `person` and set the node colour to `blue` if the node label is `cafe` ?
The AWS Neptune notebooks are using vis.js but I was not able to find anything related with my need

Any idea on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current release of the workbench does not currently support coloring by any sort of grouping. This is a feature request but I do not currently have a time line for its release.

If you want this functionality today you can achieve it by retrieving the results using python and graphing them using a tool such as pyvis.